# am try to use thead and tbody with gridview in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I want to know how to use thead and tbody in gridview in asp.net and this my html am trying to add page control presented by DataTables I have to use thead and tbody with datatables but in gridview i don't know how or where I have to put thead and tbody because in gridview there are boundfield include data field and the header text

here is the template field with a link

```
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="تعديل"> 
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="EditRecored" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' >تعديل</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is the bound field include the header text and the data field

```
                                   <asp:BoundField  DataField="Phone" 
                                HeaderText="رقم الهاتف " ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
```

```
                            <asp:BoundField  DataField="AddressEn" 
                                HeaderText="العنوان انجليزي" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
```

```
                                       <asp:BoundField  DataField="NameEn" 
                                HeaderText="اسم الحساب انجليزي" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
```

```
                                <asp:BoundField  DataField="ledgerCode" 
                                HeaderText="رقم الحساب الرئيسي" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small">
```

```
                 </Columns>
                           <RowStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                           <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DDDDDD" />
                           <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                           <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaaaa" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                               VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"/>

                       </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add thead and tbody element try this:

```
 GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
 GridView1.HeaderRow.CssClass = "yourClassName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot have custom `thead` and `tfoot` or specify it as static. Here is a workaround where you will have a `table`, `htead`, `tfoot`, then a `tbody` contains a `placeholder`. The placeholder will be filled by rows manually in code.
The code will be something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
<!-- whatever you would like to have here -->
</thead>
<tbody>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder" runat="server" />
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<!-- whatever you would like to have here -->
</tfoot>
</table>
```

and here is the C# code:

```
private void fillTBody(DataTable dt)
    {
        //Building an HTML string.
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        //Building the Data rows.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<td>");
                html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                html.Append("</td>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        ////Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        placeholder.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }
```